# How does Java know that a class can be an array?

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android development with the Big Nerd Ranch Guide where you need to create a quiz application, and am confused about how a class can be made into an array which is not specified as one.

I have created the Question class below which stores the question and answer:

```
public class Question {

    private int mTextResId;
    private boolean mAnswerTrue;

    public Question(int TextResId, boolean AnswerTrue) {
        mTextResId = TextResId;
        mAnswerTrue = AnswerTrue;

//Setters and Getter below
```

Then in the main activity have added:

```
private Question[] mQuestionArray = new Question[]{
            new Question(R.string.question_animals,true),
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
};
```

Can any class be made into an array using the `[]` after the class name?

Why is it that the Question class can be used as an array, **and** be used to collect the question with answer, even though this is not specified in the class?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> Can any class be made into an array using the [] after the class name?

Yes.

And you can even make an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of any class, should you so desire:

```
Question[][][][]
```

And you can do the same with any primitive type too:

```
int[] and int[][][][]
```